# Cartesian Product and division in relational algebra

Tags: relation-algebra

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before, I tried looking for something like it, however, I couldn't find anything.

Given two relations $R(A,B),S(B,C)$, assuming S is not empty, prove the following equality:
$$(R \times \pi_A(S)) \div \pi_A(S) \equiv R$$

**Intuitively:**

It's pretty clear that we are concatenating each entry in $R$ with every entry in $\pi_A(S)$, thus when dividing we get the relation $R$.

Is my claim correct?, if so how can I prove this formally?

Comment: It shouldn't be dividing, it should be a quotient. Also, what is $\pi_A$? Some sort of projection?

Comment: yes, $\pi_{A}$ is a projection of the attribute A.

Comment: It seems so... See [Relational Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)). We assume $A \subseteq B$. With $R \times S$ we get pairs of pairs $((a,b),(1)), ((a,b),(2)),((a,b),(3))$ where $(1),(2),(3)$ are **all** pairs of $S$. With $R \times \pi_A(S)$ we cut out all the pairs of pairs whose second pair [$(1),(2),(3)$] is **not** in $A$ [e.g. $(2)$]. Result: $((a,b),(1)), ((a,b), (3))$. If now we "divide" we get "the restrictions of tuples in R to the attribute names unique to R for which it holds that all their combinations with tuples in S are present in R."